# Add in value before single quote (')

Tags: javascript, replace

I want to add in value before the end of a single quote. Please do help me thanks!

```
var example = [['2019-02-10', 6.2]],[['2019-03-10', 6.2]]
```

After replacement

```
var example = [['2019-02-10 0:00AM' , 6.2]], [['2019-03-10 0:00AM' , 6.2]]
```

I found this code but unfortunately only for the comma.

```
var er = rep.replace(/\s*,\s*/g, " 0:00AM , ");
```

Comment: You need to be clear if that's the string representation or how it's stored in JavaScript. Can you define that data as a JavaScript variable?

Comment: yeah can i tried the code that i found and is working just that i am not sure how do i add in before the single quote instead

Comment: JavaScript code, please. Just define your `E.g.` as `var example = ...` where you put in the rest.

Comment: okay edited to var example

Comment: That's closer, but it's not 100% valid JavaScript yet. Do you want that contained within a single string, or a single array?

Comment: oh this is all in one single string and not an array

Comment: Please make the example conform to what you're actually manipulating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need some regexp to make it work, please try this

your RegExp should look like this

```
var regexp = /(\'[a-zA-Z_0-9-]+)\'?/g;
```

so you should have a string like this:

```
var st = "[['2019-02-10', 6.2]],[['2019-03-10', 6.2]]";
```

then you can replace the desired content like this

```
st.replace(regexp, "$1 0:00AM'")
```

notice that `$1` represent the first match regexp against the string

so finally you should have it like this

```
"[['2019-02-10 0:00AM', 6.2]],[['2019-03-10 0:00AM', 6.2]]"
```

I hope it can help you